# how to get the status in dry run on rsync command

Tags: bash, shell, rsync

Use case - Compare all the files and directories on the mounts ( /apps , /logs , etc ) and calculate which one is the latest and size differences.

I am trying with rsync command , but with the limitation I am not achieving exactly what I need.

Under `/tmp/test_ram` I created two directories as `dir1` and `dir2`. I have created two files under `dir1` as shown below .

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 chada users 4096 Nov 21 12:03 dir2
drwxr-xr-x 2 chada users 4096 Nov 21 12:03 dir1

cd dir1 ; ls -ltr
total 196
-rw-r--r-- 1 chada users 188510 Nov 21 12:03 file_man_rsync
-rw-r--r-- 1 chada users   6854 Nov 21 12:04 file_man_diff
```

With DryRun –

I see nothing is happening which is expected, but in the o/p size is showing as zero. Which is not I was expecting, I want to see a size in diff of files.

```
rsync -n -avrczP --out-format="%t %f %''b" --backup --backup-dir=/tmp/test_ram /tmp/test_ram/dir1/ /tmp/test_ram/dir2/


sending incremental file list
2018/11/21 12:04:55 tmp/test_ram/dir1/. 0
2018/11/21 12:04:55 tmp/test_ram/dir1/file_man_diff 0
2018/11/21 12:04:55 tmp/test_ram/dir1/file_man_rsync 0

sent 161 bytes  received 25 bytes  372.00 bytes/sec
total size is 195,364  speedup is 1,050.34 (DRY RUN)
```

the actual run :

I see the file size is showing up, which is what expected. But I cannot take chance in copying without checking. Yes I do have backup dir, but still it need too much of analysis .

```
rsync -avrczP --out-format="%t %f %''b" --backup --backup-dir=/tmp/test_ram/dir3 /tmp/test_ram/dir1/ /tmp/test_ram/dir2/


2018/11/21 12:05:52 tmp/test_ram/dir1/. 0
file_man_diff
          6,854 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=1/3)
2018/11/21 12:05:52 tmp/test_ram/dir1/file_man_diff 2.48K
file_man_rsync
        188,510 100%   16.34MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#2, to-chk=0/3)
2018/11/21 12:05:52 tmp/test_ram/dir1/file_man_rsync 56.28K

sent 58,915 bytes  received 57 bytes  117,944.00 bytes/sec
total size is 195,364  speedup is 3.31
```

This is an example I took to depict . But my comparision would be between multiple servers.

The mount points can be same , but the files are directories is what I needed to compare.

your help is much appreciated.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Thank you Barmar for the comment , I have requested there.